# Uncaught TypeError: all Spaces need to be clear for https?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website with https: .
It always showing errors for all spaces within tags (in chrome developer console).

[image: Error]

If I clear a space showing in error, it again points to the new line that containing a space/break/enter between every tags whenever I try to clear the error message.
I know it wants me to clear all the spaces between each of html tags, that unnecessary. But how can I remove for the whole thousands code containing website, text replacing is not also OK for attribute's spaces.
How can I escape that error catch. Thank you so much.

[image: code]
error line 239 is moved to line 236 for clearing spaces in this picture.

If I clear spaces in line 236 :It moved to 235

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="android-drawer mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">
      <img class="android-logo-image" src="images/text.png">
    </span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link"><b style="color:black;align:center;">Your abc</b></a>
 <!--     <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Tablets</a>          
      <div class="android-drawer-separator"></div>
      <span class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Versions</span>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Lollipop 5.0</a> -->
    </nav></div><div class="android-content mdl-layout__content" style="overflow:hidden;"><a name="top"></a><div class="android-be-together-section mdl-typography--text-center"><div class="logo-font android-slogan ">
```

Please help me .

Comment: Please show your code !!

Comment: I added to question.

Comment: Add the code means add the code, not images of it. Do you think someone will look at your images and will start typing?! I for one I won't, maybe someone else would be stronger. So please update your question.

Comment: @AungAungSwe, that is not enough, the error comes from JavaScript, so you will have to add that code too.

Comment: Thanks I want to be clear to know when it comes from, if I post my code here , you will get bored. My problem here is the console driving me to the wrong way showing basic html lines except  javascript lines. 
According to your very helpful suggestions , I clearly understand to catch it from the dom objects. Thank you so much for reading my problem.

Comment: " if I post my code here , you will get bored." if you don't show the code, we CANNOT help u.

Comment: @Dhn, sorry for my some words. Some problems are not specific, it is general and they needed to solve generally. Thank you so much for interesting my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking at it the wrong way.
The error clearly says

```
'cannot read property addEventListener of null'
```

SOLUTION 1:

This  means that you are trying to add an evenLisener on a dom object which is not present. Please look at you javascript code which is adding even listener to a null object.

SOLUTION 2:

If you are not adding any event listeners and still the error is coming then some of your library is causing this problem. Please load the libraries after the html is loaded. That may help you debug and find which library is causing the problem.

Comment: That's may be it. I think to be it. But the console driving me to the wrong way. Thanks , I am trying on it.

Comment: Ok... I guess if you look at the javascript side of the code you will figure it out. You can put break points on your javascript code and debug. All the best... If you do find the post helpful then you can upvote.